# How parse Cassandra Row into a Java POJO type

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am using datastax cassandra. I am trying to parse cassandra results into a java type and return as a json in the response.
Here each row is of type VendorToken.class (with vendorId, vendorName fields)
How to parse a row into VendorToken.class type using jackson ObjectMapper ?

```
ResultSet results = getToken(vendorId);
for(Row row : results) {
    System.out.println(row);   // Output is: Row[vendorId, testVendorName]
}
```

Or is there any otherway to parse to json? I want to return to the user in json format.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [Object Mapper](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/object_mapper/) for such things - it's not in the driver core, so you'll need to add one more dependency to your build file.  After that you could map POJO classes directly into/from Cassandra tables.

```
@Table(name = "t4", keyspace = "test")
public class Test4Data {
    @PartitionKey
    int id;

    @ClusteringColumn
    @Column(name = "c")
    int clCol;

    @Column(name = "t")
    String text;
// ... getters/setters, etc.
}

MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session);
Mapper<Test4Data> mapper = manager.mapper(Test4Data.class);
Test4Data test4Data = mapper.get(0, 1);
// output as JSON, etc.
```

If you'll need to work with multiple entries, like, querying by partition key only, etc., then you need to use [Accessors](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/object_mapper/using/#accessors), like this:

```
@Accessor
public interface UserAccessor {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    Result<User> getAll();
}

UserAccessor userAccessor = manager.createAccessor(UserAccessor.class);
Result<User> users = userAccessor.getAll();
```

and then iterate over results...

P.S. But you can get JSON from Cassandra directly using `SELECT JSON ...` ([doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useQueryJSON.html), [example](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/TestResultSerializer.java#L68)), although you have less control on how things, like, date/time, are formatted.